# Dependence relations on the rows of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help with finding the dependence relations on the rows? I know how to do it for the columns but a bit stumped with rows. I know it has something to do with a book-keeping matrix tho.

Comment: If you transpose your matrix, you'll switch rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

The rows of a matrix are the columns of its transpose.  So take the transpose and then do what you know how to do for the columns.